# Is this chemical residue on the car surface? If so, how do I repair this?

Tags: body, mazda-3, detailing

A couple weeks ago, I brought my car to a detailer. At the time, I asked the detailer to clean out some black marks that were on the white paint door surfaces on my car. I saw him use a pink bleach like substance with a cloth to clean that out.

However, I also noticed that this cleaning substance left some residue behind and I think this is what is seen on the photos below.

Would you know if that is the case and about how I can address the residue shown on the photos below?

Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: Looks like residue my carb cleaners leaves on plastic if not wiped immediately. Does it go away if wiped with a soft damp cloth?

Your best bet is to call the detailer - they will know which chemical left the residue and how to best approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like someone left car wax on the plastic. There are some plastic restorer products out there that will polish it out. But since the detailer did it, have them make it right.